# Android Studio save and retrieve image to sqlite database with ImagePath

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my app, I must save image with path to sqlite database because when I save it as BLOB, sqlite gives an error.This error is a CursowWindow.
According to research, SQLite does not support more than 2MB of data on one row.So, I have to change method.

> DBTable

```
db.execSQL("create table questions(_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
            "stuId integer," +
            "lesson text not null," +
            "subject text not null," +
            "questPhoto blob," +
            "answer text not null," +
            "questTime text," +
            "point integer not null)");
```

Images will be kept in "questPhoto".

> sorupaylas.class

The class I added to the images database.

### The method I used to save information to the database.

```
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("questTime",getDateTime().toString());
    cv.put("stuId",id_degeri);
    cv.put("lesson",txtdegiskenkontrol.getText().toString());
    cv.put("subject",konusec.getText().toString());
    cv.put("answer",textdogrucevap.getText().toString());
    cv.put("point",textsorupuan.getText().toString());
    cv.put("questPhoto",imageViewToByte(imageView));
    long id = mSQLiteDb.insert("questions",null,cv);
    Toast.makeText(sorupaylas.this, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

private byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView imageView) {
    Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray =stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

and onActivityResult

```
private void GalleryOpen() {
    GalIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent,"Select Image from Gallery"),2);
}

private void CameraOpen() {
    CamIntent =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"file"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg");
    uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
    CamIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
    CamIntent.putExtra("return-data",true);
    startActivityForResult(CamIntent,0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)  // Open Camera
        CropImage();
    else if(requestCode == 2){    // Open Gallery
        if(data!= null){
            uri=data.getData();
            CropImage();
        }
    }
    else if(requestCode == 1){
        if(data !=null){
            Bundle bundle=data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");

            Picasso.with(sorupaylas.this)
                    .load(uri)
                    .resize(1100,1100)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

### I'm getting an image of this code line.

```
byte[] getphotoOfQuest=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("questPhoto"));
                bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getphotoOfQuest,0,getphotoOfQuest.length);
```

I will be waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: How do I save and retrieve images to the database with ImagePath?

Comment: Write your bitmap to a file. Save information in the database about what file you saved it to.

Comment: Can you please show me a sample code line or link?